# How to use urandom under window to get cryptographically correct numbers?

Tags: php, random, cryptography

I know `mcrypt_create_iv($len, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)` provide high entropy under Windows, but still, how can I get a number from this? I've heard a little bit about CryptGenRandom, but I don't know how to use it under Windows.

Anyone have an idea on how I can use this to get a cryptographically correct number?

Comment: return value of mcrypt_create_iv is a string with random numbers IV, what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: On my side I get a string: Q÷:Y@îÓ|éŒžøLLA“¹¼s½Hîui2û2... :S

Comment: that's a random string (random IV), you can convert some parts of it to a number if you just want to get a random number. Like converting first 4 chars to number using their ascii code.

Comment: -_- never though about that. using ord(). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, `mcrypt_create_iv($len, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);` will correctly use CryptGenRandom for you. The PHP devs thought ahead.

As for how to get random **numbers** out of the binary string, it's [not at all straightforward](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/blob/master/lib/random_int.php).

Your best bet:

- PHP 7: Just use `random_int()`.
- PHP 5: Use `random_int()` after loading [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) as a dependency.